# How to Mellin transform a complicated Log integrand?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I got a question concerning an integral. I need to know the analytical expression. I have to Mellin transforn a function and the integral is then sth. like this:

$$ \int x^{N-1} \frac{Ln(a -x)}{1-x} dx $$

where x $\in [0,1] $ and N is the Mellin moment and $a> 1$

Actually I have to integrate this from 0 to 1 regularizing the divergence with a "plus distribution" (known in particle physics), which means the full Integral will be sth. like

$$ \int_0^1 \left( x^{N-1} \frac{Ln(a -x)}{1-x} - \frac{Ln(a -1)}{1-x} \right)dx $$

So the divergent point is going to be subtracted. For me it would be fine somehow to get the result from the integral above. But *Mathematica* doesn't want to integrate it.

What I actually need is the Integral from 0 to 1 and then an Expansion in $N\rightarrow \infty $ and finally only collecting the finite terms independent of N.

Maybe someone knows a trick how to integrate those "beasts".

---

Sorry, did a mistake in the beginning. Now the integral is correctly regularized and shouldn't diverge.

And this is what I did:

```
Integrate[(x^(-1 + N) Log[a - x])/(1 - x) - Log[a - 1 ]/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 1]

Series[Normal[%], {N, Infinity, 0}]
```

Mathematica seems to do nothing.

Ah, and N can in general be complex. Here a Ref. for the Mellin transform:
[Mellin transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html)

Comment: Although a well written question you should really also post code of what you have tried and the error message (if any) that results. I have a question about the parameters `a, `b` and `c`. Do they belong to the set of real numbers? Are they positive or is zero and negative allowed as well. Is it fair to say that `N` is an integer?

Comment: I tried `Integrate[ x^N (Log[a + b (x - c)] - Log[a - b c])/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1},
  Assumptions -> 
  b > 0 && c > 0 && a > b c && N \[Element] Integers && N >= 1]` and got an error message that it did not converge.

Comment: Hi Jack,first of all thanks for your answer. I did a mistake writing the integral. Now it should converge, at least for x=1 the Integrand should give 0. And I removed some constants which are not necessary for me.

Comment: hm, nobody has any ideas? :(

Comment: This seems like the kind of question you'd be more likely to get an answer to at [math.SE], since I suspect it'd be more readily solved by some sort of contour integration technique or something, not by a clever way of using Mathematica.

Comment: Something like this? `In[147]:= Integrate[(x^(-1 + n) Log[a - x])/(1 - x) - 
  Log[a - 1]/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a > 1, n > 1}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]

Out[147]= -((1/a)*(a*EulerGamma*Log[-1 + a] + 
     a*Log[a]*PolyGamma[0, n] + 
         Gamma[1 + n]*
      Derivative[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][
             {1, 1, 1 + n}, {2, 1 + n}, 1/a]))`

Answer (score 2):

Denote the result with I.
This logarithm has simple derivative which is 1/(a-x) with respect to a.
then factor out the parameter a to get an integrant:

```
f(x) = x^(N-1) * (1-x)^ ((N+1)-N-1) / (1-(1/a)x) / (1-x)
```

If you integrate it from zero to one with respect to x you get a Lauricella FD function which is the same as an Appell F1 function, you choose which you like, Times a beta constant of B(N,1). If F(x) is the name of the integrated f(x)

```
F(a)=a*dI/da=B(N,1)*FD(N; 1,1;N+1 ;1,1/a)
```

with a=N, b1=b2=1, c=N+1 and one argument is unity, the other 1/a

This is a function of the inverse a. Then you have to use an Euler transform to calculate a higher hypergeometric function of additional arguments + a constant.
If the Euler transform is not convenient you may expand Lauricella FD to a formal series and formally integrate (again a constant needed)

Finally you have to check one point, I would suggest a=1 to expand directly the logarithm and calculate the integration constant. The singularity will show up when expanding the series and integrate the inverse a power (this does not evaluate at zero).
Another way is to expand 1/(1-x) = Σ x^l1 and 1/(1-x/a) = Σ (x/a)^l2
Then the series is evaluated as:

```
F(a)=Σ (1/a)^(l2)/(N+l1+l2)
```

Then integrate the general term of the series to get:

```
I = c-Σ (1/a)^(l2)/(N+l1+l2)/l2
```

Apart of the constant there is a logarithmic term at l2=0 so it correctly reads:

```
I = c-ln(a)* Σ 1/(N+l1) - Σ (1/a)^(l2+1)/(N+1+l1+l2)/(l2+1)
```

then it is formally right! I do not know the convergence conditions though.
To calculate c set a=1 and expand ln(1+(1-x)) in powers of (1-x) Integrating term by term formally you get a beta function series. That can be used to find c.

Very nicely hidden intention with logarithms

Comment: How is that a Mathematica based answer? Can you back up your calculations with computations in Mathematica?